# Align text in bootstrap col fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, alignment

I have a requirement of displaying name value pairs in html using bootstrap. I am using the class "col-md-1" for name and value columns and so the data is displayed in two columns. The problem is that as bootstrap divides the screen in 12 columns, it leaves much space to the left and right of the content in field values. I tried using the classes "text-left","text-right" but it doesn't seem to work in conjunction with "col-md-*" classes. How can one align text to left or right in bootstap columns (say col-md-*) without hardcoding left or right in style to certain pixels?

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">column1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><p class="text-right">Name</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><p class="text-left">Value</p></div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column4</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column5</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column6</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column7</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column8</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column9</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column10</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column11</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">column12</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Use `'row'` class , it will avoid padding

```
 <div class="col-md-1"><p class="row text-right">Name</p></div>
 <div class="col-md-1"><p class="row text-left">Value</p></div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Htey3VVuN1)

Answer (score 4):

Hope this Help
You can use it like following

```
<div class="col-md-1 text-center">
```

For Detail have a look at following link
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RohitHarish/fL9pa313/)

Any furthur questions are welcomed

Thanks
ROHIT

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Try opening your html in a browser as against jsfiddle.

Comment: can you upload your code to fiddle i wanted to look into it ....Actually concern about the reference to bootstrap libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This code works also to center content of columns in a bootstrap row :

```
<div class="row text-center">
```